# JSON.stringify drops non-stringable values, Why is that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am having hard time to understand that JSON.stringify drops off some data which is non-stringifiable fields while working in Node.js environment.

What I don't understand are :

1. If we have valid JSON and we are having value as function, we can't stringify it :

```js
var foo = {func : function () {}};
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo))
```

2. If we have an array which contains non-stringifiable(don't understand what are they) fields, we can't stringify them instead we get null on their indexes :

```js
var arr = [function(){} , 'Walk', undefined ];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

This all comes in when I was creating a deep copy of an object and it drops off the critical data. I'm really having trouble attaching it to the question. I just need to know when the things will be dropping off in general, there must be a logic behind that. I have been skimming the web, but unable to find any resources/blog that can help me to understand the functionality behind this.

Could anyone help me understand what is it? Or share a good link or blog that can help me clear my doubts?

Comment: Why do you think that `{func : function () {}}` counts as "valid JSON"? JSON is [very precisely specified](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and supports strings, numbers, objects (again only including the allowed types), arrays, boolean and `null` as values. Nothing else. If a value is anything other, then it's not "valid JSON". JSON is (by design) **not capable** of representing arbitrary JavaScript constructs.

Comment: JSON is a _data-interchange format_. While the notation looks like JS, it's meant to be usable by various languages (JS, PHP, Java, and a lot more). Hence, it would make no sense at all to be able to store functions in them, since they would be useless in any other context than a JS application (and a function is not data)

Comment: So, any non-valid JSON won't be stringified with this static function? My question is when JSON.stringify will behave to drop the values?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I understand that, I above is not comes under valid JSON thats why it drops off the values. Is It so?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will always output JSON which respects the specifications described in the link posted by Joachim. If you read that page, you'll know what is valid. Anything else will be dropped.

Comment: @blex Thanks! I will check that link first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a data-interchange format. It is used to transmit data, independent of the language used. Generally, if some property/value is language-dependent, it is not a valid value when converted to JSON.

The [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) defines a number of value types that can be used in JSON.

For [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description), the following takes place:

- When a value is converted to JSON, it is converted to it's JSON form if suitable or it is returned as `undefined`.
- When an object is converted to JSON, each property of the object is converted to it's JSON form if suitable or it is omitted (because the converted value would be `undefined`).
- When an array is converted to JSON, each element of the array is converted to it's JSON form if suitable or it is replaced with `null`.

This behaviour can be overridden with the use of a [custom "replacer" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#parameters) passed as the second argument to `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the answer? If not please let me know.

1. You are getting {} for the outer binding, the inner func : function(){} returns undefined and therefore is not valid json.
2. You are getting null where you are trying to stringify something that cant be turned into json, i.e. undefined or a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in order to prevent unexpected, you should make sure it contains array, object, string, number, boolean and null only.

If you really need to keep the function property, you could use JSON.stringify's second parameter to describe how you want to handle it.

For example

```js
let obj = { 
  func: function () { }
}

let json = JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, value) {
  
  if (typeof value === "function") {
    return "this is a function";
  } else {
    return value;
  }
  
})

console.log(json);
```

And Mozilla web page described how it works originally.

> undefined, Functions, and Symbols are not valid JSON values. If any such values are encountered during conversion they are either omitted (when found in an object) or changed to null (when found in an array). JSON.stringify() can return undefined when passing in "pure" values like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).

[JSON.stringify() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description)